# Account Controller error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Hello guys I have a problem in the Account Controllers wanted to add a method for viewing jobs for employees, but now it is giving me an error "Not all code paths return a value"

```
      public ActionResult ViewAssignJob()
      {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var jobs = _jobService.GetEmployeeJobs(userId);
      }
```

Comment: Because if you set a return value for a method, you need to return something from the method, no matter what happens. You're not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Return View() from Actionresult and your error will gone.**

```
public ActionResult ViewAssignJob()
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var jobs = _jobService.GetEmployeeJobs(userId);
    return View(); // or  // return View(Model);
}
```

Comment: @chuma ... this error is coming because you are not returning anything in your actionresult...

Answer (score 0):

Your method's return type is `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult ViewAssignJob()
{
}
```

In these type of method you generally `return View()` or `return View(viewmodel)`.

If you don't want to return view for some debugging purpose, you could also `return content("hello world")` this will result to Hello world in a blank page

Answer (score -1):

hey you just forgot one important line as your error suggest, just put a return statement in your method so that it returns what you want. after this I am sure you will not be experiencing any problem. 
here is how your code should look like!

```
public ActionResult ViewAssignJob()


    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var jobs = _jobService.GetEmployeeJobs(userId);

        return View(jobs);
    }
```